# Dynamically initialise multiple input fields in plugin

Tags: javascript, dynamic, initialization, jquery-selectors, selector

I've many forms on one page. Each of the forms should have a phone number field. Those fields are driven by JS `plug-in`.

So I'm getting a big number of fields which should be properly initialized.
If I will do it manually I will get:
forms `*` phone input fields `=` number of initializations.

At this moment I only have the very first field working. Other doesn't initialize.

**My markup looks like**:

```
<input type="tel" class="phone_flag" name="phone_tab1[main]" required="">
<input type="tel" class="phone_flag" name="phone_tab2[main]" required="">
<input type="tel" class="phone_flag" name="phone_tab3[main]" required="">
xxx
...
```

I got a piece of advice: in order to make in properly work, I should have `querySelectorAll` with `forEach` loop. Then I should call `PhoneDisplay` function, don't pass the class name, instead pass in the element itself. Afterward, initialize the plugin on that element directly.

I only came to this solution, but it only inits the first element.

**JS init code**:

```
   document.querySelectorAll('.phone_flag').forEach(el => { 
        PhoneDisplay(el.className);     
    });

    function PhoneDisplay(ClassName){

      var input = document.querySelector('.' + `${ClassName}`);   
      var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
          hiddenInput: "full",
          initialCountry: "auto",
          geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
            $.get('proxy.php', function() {}).always(function(resp) {
              var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
              callback(countryCode);
            });
          },    
          hiddenInput: "full_phone",
          utilsScript: "intlTelInput/js/utils.js"
      });

        var reset = function() {
          input.classList.remove("error");
          errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
          errorMsg.classList.add("hide");
          validMsg.classList.add("hide");
        };

        input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
          reset();
          if (input.value.trim()) {
            if (iti.isValidNumber()) {
              validMsg.classList.remove("hide");
            } else {
              input.classList.add("error");
              var errorCode = iti.getValidationError();
              errorMsg.innerHTML = errorMap[errorCode];
              errorMsg.classList.remove("hide");
            }
          }
        });

        input.addEventListener('change', reset);
        input.addEventListener('keyup', reset);           
    }
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns the first query, so your `var input` is always the first input. You should just pass in the element itself in the forEach loop: `PhoneDisplay(el);` and then `function PhoneDisplay(input)` and remove the 'var input=' line.

Comment: Thank you! This part works, but there is one issue: the part with validation doesn't work. Any clues?

Comment: what error are you getting in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` returns the first query, so `var input` is always the first input. You should just pass in the element itself in the forEach loop: `PhoneDisplay(el);` and then `function PhoneDisplay(input)` and remove the 'var input=' line.

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var input = $("input[name=phone]");
  input.each(function() {

    intlTelInput($(this)[0], {
      initialCountry: "auto",
      nationalMode: false,
      separateDialCode: true,
      preferredCountries: ["ua", "pl", "us"],
      geoIpLookup: function(success, failure) {
        $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
          var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "us";
          success(countryCode);
        });
      },

    });
  });


});
```

Comment: Please don't just include a code snippet without explanation of why this is a solution to the problem posed by the original question. In addition, adding jQuery as a solution is not necessary and almost certainly not desirable in cases where it's not already present.